# Ionic Tab buttons with button

Tags: ionic-framework

I am thinking about placing a button with maybe a drop down menu right next to my apps other tabs but am not completely sure. Is anyone here experienced in doing something like this before?

Comment: Are you thinking about something like this http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/GpCst ?

Comment: ehh not totally, I was thinking the tabs and the buttons could be in the same 'bar' so to say..

Comment: I guess I could just modify it on my own hmm

Comment: Probably you could try to keep together in the same row <ion-tabs> and <ion-popover> (that is the button triggering the popover)